# A library used by this sketch is not installed properly

Tags: java, processing, kinect, openkinect

I have a fully functioning processing application using openkinect and a Kinect v1. When running this on my laptop, all runs perfectly, so I know it is not a code issue. I Have been trying to run the program on a different laptop and suddenly get the error "a library used by this sketch is not installed properly".

I have followed every installation step I did on the previous laptop that made it function, so do not understand why it is different now. I really need this fixed today! Here is the console log:

```
UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\stolly\Documents\Processing\libraries\openkinect_processing\library\v1\msvc\libusb-1.0.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\stolly\Documents\Processing\libraries\openkinect_processing\library\v1\msvc\libusb-1.0.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\stolly\Documents\Processing\libraries\openkinect_processing\library\v1\msvc\libusb-1.0.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
A library relies on native code that's not available.
Or only works properly when the sketch is run as a 32-bit application.
```

Comment: Its looking for a Windows library which is either not on the new laptop, or in a different path. You need to install the library, or fix the path in your application

Comment: @CocoNess but when I follow the file path the library is there?

Comment: maybe its the wrong version for the laptop, Google to find more detail wrt libusb